# How to embed my customised tensorflow layer into keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

Following is the code of one simple example for what I want to implement:

**Error**: raise TypeError("inputs must be a sequence"), TypeError: inputs must be a sequence

How to solve this to make the program can work? Any help will be appreciated.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Flatten
import numpy as np
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
import tensorflow as tf


class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  

    def call(self, x):
        "Some other tf function will be put at here"
        outputs, state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockCell(32), x, dtype=tf.float32)
        return outputs

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape


def get_model(timesteps, data_dim):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))
    model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(MyLayer())  # this is my layer

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    return model


def run_demo():
    data_dim = 16
    timesteps = 8
    num_classes = 10

    model = get_model(timesteps, data_dim)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
    """Generate the traning and validation data"""
    x_train = np.random.random((1000, timesteps, data_dim))
    y_train = np.random.random((1000, num_classes))
    x_val = np.random.random((100, timesteps, data_dim))
    y_val = np.random.random((100, num_classes))

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_demo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am not too familiar with Recurrent Model.

But I think the problem is input size.

The size into custom layer (?, 8, 32)
but tf.nn.static_rnn require list like

[image]

so you need to change the input size then problem will fix.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Flatten, Dense

class MyLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(32)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        "Some other tf function will be put at here"
        rnn_inputs = tf.unstack(x, axis=1)
        outputs, state = tf.nn.static_rnn(self.cell, rnn_inputs, dtype=tf.float32)
        for i in range(len(outputs)):
            outputs[i] = tf.expand_dims(outputs[i], axis=1)
        outputs = tf.concat(outputs, axis=1)
        return outputs

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

def get_model(timesteps, data_dim):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))
    model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(MyLayer())  # this is my layer

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    return model

def run_demo():
    data_dim = 16
    timesteps = 8
    num_classes = 10

    model = get_model(timesteps, data_dim)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
    """Generate the traning and validation data"""
    x_train = np.random.random((1000, timesteps, data_dim))
    y_train = np.random.random((1000, num_classes))
    x_val = np.random.random((100, timesteps, data_dim))
    y_val = np.random.random((100, num_classes))

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_demo()
```